# SVG Morphing animation giving really weird results

Tags: javascript, svg, anime.js, svg-morphing

```js
anime({
            targets: ".a",
            d: [
                {value: "M0,0,33.32,31.1l89.963,43.315L146.606,0Z"}
            ],
            easing: "easeOutQuad",
            duration: 2000,
            loop: false,
        });
```

```css
  html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        svg {
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

        path {
            fill:none;
            stroke:#8103ff;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>



<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="149.606" height="92.963" viewBox="0 0 149.606 92.963">
        <path class="a" d="M0,0V89.963L123.282,74.414,146.606,0Z">
 </svg>
 
<br>
<h5>The SVGs in their raw forms: </h5>
 
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="149.606" height="92.963" viewBox="0 0 149.606 92.963">
        <path d="M0,0V89.963L123.282,74.414,146.606,0Z">
 </svg>
 
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="149.606" height="92.963" viewBox="0 0 149.606 92.963">
        <path d="M0,0,33.32,31.1l89.963,43.315L146.606,0Z">
 </svg>
```

So I have this SVG that I want to morph, with anime.js. And also, the SVG code is exported via Adobe XD.

I'm having trouble realising SVG morphing animations of any kind. Even the easiest ones. The end result is weird.

I tried searching on Stack Overflow and other sites but I didn't really find anything that could fix my problem. I tried redrawing the shape 10 times carefully, looking to draw the same amount of Anchor Points on both of the SVGs. But it's still failing to draw the animation properly.

Let's say I have these 2 SVGs, having experienced really "suttle" changes.

Thing is, I'd expect them to go gracefully from one state to another but instead they just morph out of place and weirdly. Is it something that I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: That second path seems to begin with two move commands. I changed them to all line commands (also converted the V command to an L command ) and it seemed to work: https://jsfiddle.net/x1b5ac2y/ Adobe does some strange optimisation stuff. You'll have to do some post processing.

Comment: Yeah, look, thing is, I tried using Figma as well, but unfortunately I've seen the same result. Will I have to learn how to tweak the data points myself?

Comment: Try using the same number of points and the same commands

Comment: A while back I had to create an adobe generated SVG to canvas command translator. To make it work I had to process the paths to translate short form commands, like V and H, relative commands, using lowercase letters and shapes that canvas does not natively support, like ellipsis. You may have to do something similar. Adobe tries to simplify paths which makes inconsistant paths. You will have to tweak the data points yourself, but you can create or modify a tool to do it for you.

Comment: Oh, alright, thank you. I'll try and look into what you told me, and if I find a solution that will work for me good, I'll post an answer to this question. Thankies for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes points get reduced and or flipped when saving a vector as an svg. It sucks when trying to morph between shapes. Try this:

https://shapeshifter.design/.

Import your initial shape then click on animate path. Then in the from to portion paste in the path data for the second shape then if there are issues add points as necessary then drag the points around to a position that makes the paths compatible.

Then add another path animation with the results from the last one as the from and paste the data for the third morph position in the to area then edit.

Once satisfied you can copy and paste the path data that is working into your project.